# Parse Migration Issue

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, database-migration, back4app, database

I have lost my data base because I am not able to migrate parse database.
Please give us suggestions. Is it able to get my database from parse server ?
I was pay for it.I have not any back up of my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't migrate before the end of January, and you don't have any backups, all your data is probably lost. 
You can try emailing the Parse.com migration team at migration@parse.com. But as you had a year to migrate,  I doubt they will be able to help, even if they have backups.

Comment: Hi @EReid could you read my question here and tell me if I am in the same boat? I thought I had migrated correctly over a year ago but I have ran into issues over the past month and think I must have done something wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42353018/parse-migration-error-to-mlabs-and-heroku