# Parse migration Error to mLabs and Heroku

Tags: swift, xcode, heroku, parse-platform, sdk

I migrated my parse db to Mlabs at least a year ago. I have been working on the app since and parse dashboard said I had migrated successfully. Mlab and Parse were both receiving updates to their databases.

However in the last week or two the app no longer goes past the login page. No code has beed adjusted its a server problem. Here is the error that prints in Xcode logs:

> UserInfo={code=100, originalError=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "(null)", temporary=0, error=The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)

Now I figured maybe I missed a step in the migration process which is very plausible as I am a novice coder. So I followed this [tutorial](https://learnappmaking.com/how-to-migrate-parse-app-parse-server-heroku-mongolab/) to Migrate Your Parse App To Parse Server With Heroku And mLab. 
I have followed each step and had success up until the last step: heroku open. It should open a web page that says I dream of being a web site but the page that opens is this:

[image: heroku open error]

When I check heroku logs it says:

```
2017-02-20T19:01:27.142050+00:00 app[web.1]: > parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /app
2017-02-20T19:01:27.142052+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-20T19:01:27.142051+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597494+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597507+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/requiredParameter.js:8
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597508+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw errorMessage;
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597509+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597515+00:00 app[web.1]: You must provide a serverURL!
```

***Edit it was the serverURL was not updated in my index.js Now Heroku loads 'I dream of being a website'.

Comment: serverURL  is missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the logs show your `serverURL` is missing. In your `index.js` you can add it to your constructor then redeploy on heroku:

```
var api = new ParseServer({
   databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
   cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
   appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'xxxxxx',
   masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'zzzzz',
   restAPIKey: 'yyyyyy',
   serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',
});
```

Comment: That worked in getting the 'heroku open' to open on the 'I dream of being a website'. However when I run it in xcode it stills gives the original error in xcode above: '(NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)'. I'm not sure do I open a new question or ask here on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597507+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/parse-server/lib/requiredParameter.js:8
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597508+00:00 app[web.1]:   throw errorMessage;
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597509+00:00 app[web.1]:   ^
2017-02-20T19:01:28.597515+00:00 app[web.1]: You must provide a serverURL!
```

These lines seem to suggest you have forgotten to include a serverURL in your app main file. 
If I recall correctly, there might have been additional required parameters that were added through updates. Not sure if serverURL is one of these, but it seems like it would have been in from the start.

Anyway, if you put a serverURL when you create the Parse Server app, this shouldn't happen. 
If it does, there must be an error in the file beforehand